# truffle: Error while creating instance of the contract - no code at address 0x3800e97896c6fdb614b9d011c9344dea32e49047

Tags: node.js, ethereum, truffle

I have deployed a simple 'HelloWorld' contract on the ethereum node using truffle. I am trying to access and call a function inside the contract with a node API.

Below is the code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
const artifact = require('./../ethereumapp/example/smartContract/build/contracts/HelloWorld.json')
const contract = require('truffle-contract');
const HelloWorldContract = contract(artifact);

var web3 = new Web3('http://localhost:8000');
HelloWorldContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
var contractapp = HelloWorldContract.at('0x3800e97896c6fdb614b9d011c9344dea32e49047').catch((err)={
    //Error gets thrown here
    console.error("Error in creating instance of HelloWorld :"+err)}
);

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("Hey! The app is up and running");
});

app.get('/getMessage',(req,res)=>{
    console.log('Invoking smart contract...');
    res.send(contractapp.getMessage());
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log("App started on 3000");
});
```

I am new to ethereum/truffle and can't find out why this error is thrown. Please provide any sample nodejs code which can help me sort out this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error occurred because the contract deployment transaction was running out of gas. Truffle's default gas limit used for deploys is `6721975` (reference: [truffle general options](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#general-options)).

Here's the help text that appeared for the deployment dry-run explanining the issue:

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"LinearLiquidityPool" ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) caused gas estimation to fail. Try:
   * Making your contract constructor more efficient
   * Setting the gas manually in your config or as a deployment parameter
   * Using the solc optimizer settings in 'truffle-config.js'
   * Setting a higher network block limit if you are on a
     private network or test client (like ganache).
```